# Debugging a Firebase Client Connection

Tags: javascript, websocket, firebase

We have a user reporting that their data isn't loading in our app and we're having trouble debugging why this is happening.

We're currently screen sharing with this user and it turns out that a call like this never returns:

`new Firebase("http://gamma.firebase.com/path/to/our/data").once('value', function(r) { console.log(r); });`

Yet this works fine from other clients.

I don't even know how we would go about debugging this. How would we determine why the callback isn't firing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some proxies block our real-time transport code. We're working to resolve this, but in the meantime, try using an SSL connection like this:

```
new Firebase("https://...");
```

We actually recommend that all production apps use SSL.